# Grok Filter want to see only the processname

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to see only the Process cmd.exe.

Example:

```html
New Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  Token Elevation Type: %%1938  Creator Process ID: 0x1a0`enter code here`
```

Grok Filter:

```html
New Process Name: %{GREEDYDATA}\\%{GREEDYDATA:Process}
```

Output:

```html
{
  "Process": [
    [
      "cmd.exe  Token Elevation Type: %%1938  Creator Process ID: 0x1a0`enter code here`"
    ]
  ]
}
```

How i get to see only cmd.exe and not Token Elevation Type: %%1938  Creator Process ID: 0x1a0`enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GREEDYDATA usually means "everything".  I find it usually not be useful except at the end of a pattern (as a catch-all).

So, you're asking for everything after the backslash, which is what you're getting.

How about:

```
New Process Name: %{GREEDYDATA}\\%{NOTSPACE:Process}
```